# how to know if file is still open for writing

Tags: php

i have a function that writes to a file , how can i using another script check if the file is being used for writing or it is closed ?

**Edit :** this file might be opened for writing by other script/application/system ...

thank you .

Comment: look on flock examples : http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/8/11/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`flock`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) in both scripts.  This puts a flag on the file so that other scripts are informed that the file is in use.  The flag is turned off either intentionally using `fclose` or implicitly by the end of the script.

Comment: While flock is the answer (or `dio_fcntl`), flock only provides an *advisory* lock. You have to coordinate **everywhere** with flock. Any other script not using flock can manipulate the file at any time.

Comment: @jasonbar Hence by "in both scripts". After your first comment, I had updated my answer to reflect your excellent point.

Comment: Yeah, I figured you knew what was going on, the wording was just a bit ambiguous. +1

Comment: any other solution , this file might be opened for writing by other script/application/system ...

Comment: @Rohan, this covers cross script / application cases. What do you mean by "system"? Another physical (or virtual) machine?

Comment: i mean that the file could be opened for writing by a system module , a user using some application or another php/perl script . how can i check if the file is opened for writing or not . thats all (flock won't work here)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Unix, your system might have the [lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) ("LiSt Open Files") command installed.
The "FD" column in the output indicates whether the file was opened for reading,
writing, or both.

I'd like to point out that any process of the form "check to see if file X is open for writing, if so do something..." is subject to a race condition.  Some other process
could open the file after you've checked, but before the action was started.

Comment: @Ronan: In Windows, it's easier -- the LockFile function allows guaranteed exclusive access to a file (or even part of a file).  Most Unix filesystems only provide *advisory* locks, which aren't necessarily respected by other processes beyond your control, so file locking is not a good design choice for that environment.  lsof or `flock()` may get you part of the way there.

Answer (score -3):

I'd say just use the file open function, if it returns false, then the file's obviously still open.

Comment: You can call fopen() on the same file as many times as you like, from as many scripts as you like.